Google sheets sum functions
How can I sum a column on a sheet on a different sheet from the beginning of the year to the current date on Google sheets

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Please [edit] your question and insert a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a blank sheet maker that lets you share safely.

Use filter(), like this:
=sum(ifna(filter( 
  Sheet2!B2:B, 
  Sheet2!A2:A <= today(), 
  year(Sheet2!A2:A) = year(today()) 
)))

See filter().
